# Puppet Apache mod_alias config

Tags: puppet, puppetlabs-apache

I am trying to pass parameters to a class but am running into a Duplicate declaration error. The docs state this: https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-apache#class-apachemodalias

The following yields:
`Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Resource Statement, Duplicate declaration: Apache::Mod[alias] is already declared`

```
class { 'apache':
  server_signature  => 'off',
  trace_enable      => 'off',
  mpm_module        => 'prefork'
}

include apache::mod::headers
include apache::mod::rewrite
class { 'apache::mod::alias':
  icons_options => 'None',
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `default_mods` parameter for apache needs to be set since the apache module includes the alias module as a default. The following will disable all default modules allowing you to explicitly define your own.

`default_mods        => false`

```
class { 'apache':
  server_signature  => 'off',
  trace_enable      => 'off',
  mpm_module        => 'prefork',
  default_mods        => false
}

include apache::mod::headers
include apache::mod::rewrite
class { 'apache::mod::alias':
  icons_options => 'None',
}
```

Comment: I think it's more clear, if you use hiera to store the class parameters.